# How can I get the page's uri when using a GoBack method in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

**Context:**
1. Windows Phone 7.5 and above
2. PageA navigates to PageB using "this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Help.xaml", UriKind.Relative));"
3. PageB goes back to PageA using NavigationService.GoBack();
4. In pageA, I want to check if it came from pageB

I use "NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();" in OnNavigatedTo method of pageA,  but since the GoBack() will delete the source page, I can't get the right result?

How do pageA knows it's navigate back from pageB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is done by the canGo Forward Prop.

```
void forwardButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
    {
        this.NavigationService.GoForward();
    }
}
```

if CanGoForward is false then it has no forward stack in the navigation service

For a work around save the page name in

Say

```
Application.Current.Resources("LastPage", "MainPage.xaml");
```

and check if it can go forward and the last page name will indicate the page you were in

Comment: Thanks, that's it! At last, I create a property in App class and use it to share the pagename. It seems there is no built-in feature for this :)

Answer (score 0):

In PageA you can override the `OnNavigatingFrom` method, the parameter have `Uri` value which is the page which is the origin of the navigation.

Comment: OnNavigatingFrom  will never fire when GoBack() from pageB to pageA